# Flutter Project Not Building in Xcode Cloud

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode-cloud, xcode-archive

If you all know anything about these errors below your help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information about this feel free to comment. I'm pretty lost at this point. I've been archiving my Flutter app with Xcode Cloud and am getting these four errors (Btw it archives and builds normally on my own machine):

- `could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig' in search paths`
- `could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths`
- `Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'`
- `Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist'`

I'm also getting these two warnings (Idk if they're related):

- `Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase.`
- `Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'`

I'm using the defualt workflow for Xcode Cloud and am using the following as my post clone script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# The default execution directory of this script is the ci_scripts directory.
cd $CI_WORKSPACE # change working directory to the root of your cloned repo.

# Install Flutter using git.
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b stable $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"

# Install Flutter artifacts for iOS (--ios), or macOS (--macos) platforms.
flutter precache --ios

# Install Flutter dependencies.
flutter pub get
flutter build ios

# Install CocoaPods using Homebrew.
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 # disable homebrew's automatic updates.
brew install cocoapods

# Install CocoaPods dependencies.
cd ios
pod install # run `pod install` in the `ios` directory.

exit 0
```

I've tried making changes to the post-clone script and the project itself, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I used the [script](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#xcode-cloud) almost as-is and it worked for iOS on Xcode Cloud. I faced a similar issue with the macOS build. I had to add the `flutter build macos` same as you and it fixed the problem but I had a different issue related to the Mac Development cert signing.